# Python multiprocessing issue / misunderstanding

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm having an issue with multiprocessing; I'm using python2.7 on linux 2.6.36.  I know this would be much easier with a higher level module or library but I'm trying to use the lower level functions (os.fork() and os.exec*) to ensure I really understand- This is kind of a learning exercise.

Below is my code, it's a multiprocessing 'ping' utility.  The issue is while it seems to run, it throws an OSError every so often on the os.wait() line. "No child processes"

That doesn't make sense to me as os.wait() should only be called when the program catches a signal that a child process has exited and needs to be reaped.

Following the code is sample output.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import os
import time
import sys
import signal

kids = []

def chldClean(SIG, FRM):
    global kids
    pid, status = os.wait()
    kids.pop(kids.index(pid))

signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, chldClean)

hosts = ( '10.98.232.66',
          '10.86.144.241',
          '10.86.144.242',
          '10.98.193.130',
          '10.98.198.130',
          '10.86.116.161',
          '10.86.120.161',
          '10.99.21.254',
          '10.97.98.102',
          '10.97.111.180' )


while True:
    for HOST in hosts:
        while len(kids) > 7:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid == 0:
            os.closerange(0, 4)
            os.execl('/bin/ping', 'PING', '-c', '1', '-w', '2', HOST)
        else:
            kids.append(pid)
            print kids
```

Sample Output with Errors below ----------------------------------------

```
[18188]
[18188, 18189]
[18188, 18189, 18190]
[18188, 18189, 18190, 18191]
[18188, 18189, 18190, 18191, 18192]
[18188, 18189, 18190, 18191, 18192, 18193]
[18188, 18189, 18190, 18191, 18192, 18193, 18194]
[18188, 18189, 18190, 18191, 18192, 18193, 18194, 18195]
[18188, 18189, 18191, 18192, 18193, 18194, 18195, 18196]
[18188, 18191, 18192, 18193, 18194, 18195, 18196, 18197]
[18188, 18191, 18192, 18194, 18195, 18196, 18197, 18198]
[18191, 18192, 18194, 18195, 18196, 18197, 18198, 18201]
[18191, 18194, 18195, 18196, 18197, 18198, 18201, 18202]
[18191, 18195, 18196, 18197, 18198, 18201, 18202, 18203]
[18195, 18196, 18197, 18198, 18201, 18202, 18203, 18204]
[18196, 18197, 18198, 18202, 18203, 18204, 18205]
[18196, 18197, 18198, 18202, 18203, 18204, 18205, 18206]
[18197, 18198, 18202, 18203, 18204, 18205, 18206, 18207]
[18198, 18203, 18204, 18205, 18206, 18207, 18210]
[18198, 18203, 18204, 18205, 18206, 18207, 18210, 18211]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sunmon-mp", line 33, in <module>
    pid = os.fork()
  File "./sunmon-mp", line 12, in chldClean
    pid, status = os.wait()
OSError: [Errno 10] No child processes
[18203, 18204, 18205, 18206, 18207, 18210, 18211, 18212]
[18203, 18204, 18206, 18207, 18210, 18211, 18212, 18213]
[18203, 18204, 18206, 18207, 18211, 18212, 18213, 18214]
[18203, 18204, 18206, 18207, 18211, 18212, 18214, 18215]
[18203, 18204, 18206, 18207, 18212, 18214, 18215, 18217]
[18203, 18204, 18206, 18207, 18214, 18215, 18217, 18218]
[18203, 18204, 18206, 18207, 18215, 18217, 18218, 18219]
[18204, 18206, 18207, 18215, 18217, 18218, 18219, 18220]
[18204, 18206, 18207, 18217, 18218, 18219, 18220, 18221]
[18206, 18207, 18217, 18218, 18219, 18220, 18221, 18223]
[18207, 18217, 18218, 18219, 18220, 18221, 18223, 18224]
[18217, 18218, 18219, 18220, 18221, 18223, 18224, 18225]
[18217, 18219, 18220, 18221, 18223, 18224, 18225, 18226]
[18217, 18219, 18220, 18221, 18223, 18225, 18226, 18227]
[18217, 18219, 18220, 18221, 18223, 18226, 18227, 18228]
[18217, 18220, 18221, 18223, 18226, 18227, 18228, 18229]
[18217, 18220, 18221, 18223, 18227, 18228, 18229, 18230]
[18217, 18220, 18221, 18223, 18227, 18228, 18230, 18231]
[18220, 18221, 18223, 18227, 18228, 18230, 18231, 18233]
[18221, 18223, 18227, 18228, 18230, 18231, 18233, 18234]
[18223, 18227, 18228, 18230, 18231, 18233, 18234, 18235]
[18223, 18227, 18228, 18231, 18233, 18234, 18235, 18236]
[18223, 18227, 18228, 18231, 18233, 18234, 18236, 18237]
[18223, 18227, 18228, 18231, 18233, 18234, 18237, 18239]
[18227, 18228, 18231, 18233, 18234, 18237, 18239, 18240]
[18228, 18231, 18233, 18234, 18237, 18239, 18240, 18241]
[18228, 18231, 18233, 18237, 18239, 18240, 18241, 18242]
[18231, 18233, 18237, 18239, 18240, 18241, 18242, 18243]
[18231, 18233, 18239, 18240, 18241, 18242, 18243, 18244]
[18231, 18233, 18239, 18240, 18242, 18243, 18244, 18245]
[18231, 18233, 18239, 18242, 18243, 18244, 18245, 18246]
[18231, 18233, 18242, 18243, 18244, 18245, 18246, 18247]
[18233, 18242, 18243, 18244, 18245, 18246, 18247, 18248]
[18242, 18243, 18244, 18245, 18246, 18247, 18248, 18249]
[18243, 18244, 18245, 18246, 18247, 18248, 18249, 18250]
[18243, 18245, 18246, 18247, 18248, 18249, 18250, 18251]
[18243, 18245, 18247, 18248, 18249, 18250, 18251, 18252]
[18243, 18245, 18248, 18249, 18250, 18251, 18252, 18253]
[18243, 18245, 18249, 18250, 18251, 18252, 18253, 18254]
[18243, 18245, 18249, 18250, 18252, 18253, 18254, 18255]
[18245, 18249, 18250, 18252, 18253, 18254, 18255, 18258]
[18249, 18250, 18252, 18253, 18254, 18255, 18258, 18259]
[18249, 18250, 18253, 18254, 18255, 18258, 18259, 18260]
[18249, 18250, 18253, 18254, 18255, 18258, 18260, 18261]
[18249, 18250, 18253, 18254, 18255, 18260, 18261, 18262]
[18250, 18253, 18254, 18255, 18260, 18261, 18262, 18263]
[18253, 18254, 18255, 18260, 18261, 18262, 18263, 18264]
[18253, 18254, 18255, 18261, 18262, 18263, 18264, 18265]
[18253, 18254, 18255, 18261, 18262, 18264, 18265, 18266]
[18254, 18255, 18261, 18262, 18264, 18265, 18266, 18267]
[18255, 18261, 18262, 18264, 18265, 18266, 18267, 18268]
[18261, 18262, 18264, 18265, 18266, 18267, 18268, 18269]
[18261, 18262, 18265, 18266, 18267, 18268, 18269, 18270]
[18261, 18262, 18265, 18266, 18267, 18268, 18270, 18271]
[18261, 18262, 18265, 18266, 18267, 18270, 18271, 18273]
[18261, 18262, 18265, 18266, 18270, 18271, 18273, 18274]
[18261, 18262, 18265, 18266, 18271, 18273, 18274, 18275]
[18261, 18262, 18265, 18266, 18271, 18273, 18275, 18276]
[18262, 18265, 18266, 18271, 18273, 18275, 18276, 18277]
[18262, 18265, 18266, 18273, 18275, 18276, 18277, 18278]
[18265, 18266, 18273, 18276, 18277, 18278, 18280]
[18265, 18266, 18273, 18276, 18277, 18278, 18280, 18281]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sunmon-mp", line 33, in <module>
    pid = os.fork()
  File "./sunmon-mp", line 12, in chldClean
    pid, status = os.wait()
OSError: [Errno 10] No child processes
[18265, 18273, 18276, 18277, 18278, 18280, 18282]
[18265, 18276, 18277, 18278, 18280, 18281, 18282, 18283]
[18265, 18276, 18278, 18281, 18282, 18283, 18284]
[18265, 18276, 18278, 18281, 18282, 18283, 18284, 18285]
[18265, 18276, 18278, 18282, 18283, 18284, 18285, 18286]
[18265, 18276, 18278, 18283, 18284, 18286, 18289]
[18265, 18276, 18278, 18283, 18284, 18286, 18289, 18290]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sunmon-mp", line 33, in <module>
    pid = os.fork()
  File "./sunmon-mp", line 12, in chldClean
    pid, status = os.wait()
OSError: [Errno 10] No child processes
[18265, 18276, 18278, 18283, 18284, 18289, 18290, 18291]
[18276, 18278, 18283, 18284, 18289, 18290, 18291, 18292]
[18276, 18278, 18283, 18284, 18290, 18291, 18292, 18293]
[18276, 18278, 18283, 18284, 18290, 18291, 18293, 18294]
[18276, 18278, 18283, 18284, 18290, 18291, 18294, 18295]
[18278, 18283, 18284, 18290, 18291, 18294, 18295, 18297]
[18283, 18284, 18290, 18291, 18294, 18295, 18297, 18298]
[18283, 18284, 18290, 18291, 18295, 18297, 18298, 18299]
```

Comment: You should use `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead of `#!/usr/bin/python2.7`

Comment: Did you look up the "No child processes" error?  If so, please reduce the size of your code (and output) to something small and focused.  And include the definition you found of the "No child processes" error.  Please **update** your question to be easier to read without scrolling.

Comment: @ThiefMaster the env python on this system is 3.1.3- i want to use python2.7 which is also on this system

Comment: @S.Lott I can get the same error when just calling os.wait() when there are no un-reaped child processes- pretty straight forward error.  Im not sure where the issue is because I don't think os.wait() should be called unless the program gets a signal there is an exited child process. Hence my need for clarification.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? If you want to learn the low level side of all of this why not write in C? The Python libraries are included for a reason. Either use the subprocess or multiprocessing module.

Comment: @Falmarri: have you no sense of curiosity? i wonder what weird chain of events causes this to happen

Comment: @Claudiu You're right. I never set out to make something as seemingly silly as this, but now I'm here and its not working as expected and I want to know -why-  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are being affected by a [bug causing child processes to inherit pending signals](http://bugs.python.org/issue9535).  That would explain why the stack trace appears more than once.  The child is trying to wait on its own non-existent child.

Also more than one queued signal of the same type may be handled at once, so I don't recommend using wait() in the signal handler.

Comment: If i don't use wait() in the signal handler, how do i reap an exited child?

Comment: Set a flag in the signal handler when it is handled.  Then, when you detect the flag is set, wait() until you receive the "No child processes" error and clear the flag.  If you want to block instead of spin waiting on the flag, check out signal.set_wakeup_fd or you can home brew by writing a byte to a pipe in the signal handler.

Comment: I think you are correct about this bug.  If I test for the pid against the parent in the reaping function, it stops throwing errors 

`if os.getpid() == ParentPID: os.wait() .....`

Answer (score 1):

You might have the same race condition problem that is described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340283/avoiding-a-fork-sigchld-race-condition). Unfortunately, I can't test your code right now (Windows environment, so no *SIGCHLD*) but it seems that if you use `os.waitpid(-1, os.WNOHANG)` on the problematic line 12, you wouldn't get the error. You still get no guarantee that you won't run into the race condition described above, though.

Comment: replacing os.wait() with os.waitpid does not clear up the exceptions. :(

Comment: Maybe you really don't have any child processes despite the value of the `kids` list. You should have 7-8 `ping` processes running most of the time; what does a `ps -a` say? Do you really? If it turns out you don't, then you know why `os.wait()` throws an error.