# no attribute '_popen'" in <Finalize object, dead> when binding signals handlers in Python

Tags: python, signals, warnings, multiprocessing

Whenever subclassing `mulitprocessing.Process` class and binding the `SIGCHLD` signal into it, the python interpreter raises the following error:

```
Exception AttributeError: "'MyClass' object has no attribute '_popen'" in <Finalize object, dead> ignored
```

But my class has the expected behavior though.

Here's how what the signal handling looks like:

```
import os 
import signal
import multiprocessing

class Actor(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bind_signals_handlers()
        ...
        super(Actor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def on_children_exit(self):
        """Signal handler to be called on SIGCHLD.

        This handler will be called on every SIGCHLD signal received
        by the actor. SIGCHLD is raised on process interuptions and on
        process death, so you can override this handler to set up
        the behavior you'd like.

        As a default this handler will check if a child process
        as exited, and that's it.
        """
        # Make sure we do the waitpid over the parent process
        # and not from any children.
        # see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783183/python-multiprocessing-issue-misunderstanding
        # see http://bugs.python.org/issue9535
        if os.getpid() == self.pid:
            pid, status = os.waitpid(-1, os.WNOHANG)
            if pid:
                print "Actor's child with pid {} exited".format(pid)

    def bind_signals_handlers(self):
        def sig_child_handler(signum, frame):
            self.on_children_exit()
        def sig_shutdown_handler(signum, frame):
            self.stop()

        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sig_shutdown_handler)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sig_shutdown_handler)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, sig_child_handler)
```

Any idea of what's causing the warning, and how to fix it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution by catching the `AttributeError` and inspecting the traceback. It happens that accessing the `pid` attribute on a `multiprocessing.Process` instance before it has been started raises an `AttributeError`.

I haven't found any documentation about it.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question while researching a similar exception:

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in start
    assert self._popen is None, 'cannot start a process twice'
AttributeError: 'MyProcess' object has no attribute '_popen'
```

In my case, the root of the problem was that I had forgotten to call the constructor for `Process` in the appropriate place:

```
class MyProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, settings):
        super(MyProcess, self).__init__() # Don't forget this!
        ...
```

Clearly the call is present in the original question, but as it's being called at the end of the child class constructor, I'd be unsurprised if this were the cause (though I'm not sure if moving the call is the the appropriate remedy in this particular case).