# How to keep track of child processes

Tags: linux, perl, fork

So my program spawns a number of child processes in response to certain events, and I'm doing something ike this to keep track and kill them upon program exit (Perl syntax):

```
my %children = ();

# this will be called upon exit
sub kill_children {
  kill 'INT' => keys %children;
  exit;
}

# main code

while(1) {

   ...
   my $child = fork();

   if ($child > 0) {
     $children{$child} = 1;
   } elsif ($child == 0) {
     # do child work ...
     exit();
   } else {
     # handle the error
   }
}
```

So the idea is as above. However, there's a blatant race condition there, in that a given child can start and terminate before the father has a chance to run and record its pid in the %children hash. So the father may end up thinking that a given pid belongs to an active child, even if this child has terminated.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to accomplish in a safe way?

Edit: To better keep track of children, the code can be extended as follows (which however also suffer of the exact same race condition, so that's why I didn't write it fully in the first place):

```
my %children = ();

sub reap {
  my $child;
  while (($child = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG)) > 0) {
    #print "collecting dead child $child\n";
    delete $children{$child};
  }
}

$SIG{CHLD} = \&reap;

# this will be called upon exit
sub kill_children {
  local $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';
  kill 'INT' => keys %children;
  exit;
}

# main code

while(1) {

   ...
   my $child = fork();

   if ($child > 0) {
     $children{$child} = 1;
   } elsif ($child == 0) {
     # do child work ...
     exit();
   } else {
     # handle the error
   }
}
```

Even in this case, the contents of %children may not reflect the actual active children.

**Edit 2:** I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340283/avoiding-a-fork-sigchld-race-condition), which is exactly about the same problem. I like the solution suggested in there.

Comment: This is not about Perl. The same problem would exist in just about any language.

Comment: Your example is in Perl, which emulates `fork` on platforms that don't have it. This has possible consequences for the answer.

Comment: I could write the exact same example in C, and the question would still be valid. In any case, I'm running under Linux.

Answer (score 2):

On UNIX it's not a race condition. This is the standard way to handle `fork()`. When the child process exits, its status is changed to "terminated"; it becomes a [zombie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process). It still has an entry in the process table until the parent process calls one of the `wait` functions. Only after that is the dead process really removed.

Even if the parent sets itself up to ignore SIGCHLD, it still wouldn't qualify as a *race condition*; the parent would just have a PID that's not valid anymore. In that case, `wait()` would return ECHILD. **But** setting SIGCHLD would free up a child's PID, possibly leading to the parent trying to kill a process that is not a child.

On Windows, which doesn't have a `fork` call, it is emulated by creating a thread in the perl process. See [perlfork](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html). I'm not knowlegable enough about Windows to opinionate about if that could cause a race condition, but I suspect not.

Comment: Not necessarily: the handler for SIGCHLD could be set to SIG_IGN and children never become zombies, without the father needing to call wait().

Comment: or you can use double fork preventing zombies.

Comment: @homer5439 If you set the parent to ignore SIGCHLD, why then make it keep a list of child process PIDs?

Comment: Because I want to kill them and clean up when the program ends. I'll edit the question to reformulate the question and provide more details.

Comment: @homer5439 That's what the `wait` system calls are for.